# How to explain that a place has alternative names?

Tags: vocabulary

I am trying to explain to someone that Sao Paulo´s airport can be referred to in different ways. I believe my text is incorrect but I do not know how to fix it. Is the following phrase correct?

"You may find it by the name of GRU airport, Sao Paulo International Airport  or Guarulhos airport."

Answer (score -1):

It is normal to use the phrase *also known as* (or *aka*) in this situation. From [yourdictionary.com](https://www.yourdictionary.com/also-known-as):

> **[also-known-as](https://www.yourdictionary.com/also-known-as)**
>   *Adverb*
>   *(not comparable)*
>   (idiomatic) Used to introduce an alternative name; alias.

*It is called the GRU Airport, also known as Sao Paulo International Airport or Guarulhos Airport.*